# cvConvertScale error

Tags: opencv, python-2.7

I am new to Python and openCV so if this is simple I apologize in advance.
I am trying to follow the depth map code at http://altruisticrobot.tistory.com/219.
In the code below `ConvertScale` raises the following error:

```
src.size == dst.size && src.channels() == dst.channels()
```

I have spent a couple days and cant figure out why.
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
im_l = cv.LoadImage('C:\Python27\project\captureL6324.png',cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
im_r = cv.LoadImage('C:\Python27\project\captureR6324.png',cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
imsize = cv.GetSize(im_l)
disp = cv.CreateImage(imsize,cv.IPL_DEPTH_16S,1)# to receive Disparity
#run stereo Correspondence-- returns a single channel 16 bit signed disparity
disparity = cv.FindStereoCorrespondenceBM(im_r,im_l,disp,cv.CreateStereoBMState())
#convert to a real disparity by dividing it by 16-- first create variable to hold the  converted scale
real_disparity = cv.CreateImage(imsize,cv.IPL_DEPTH_16S,1)
cv.ConvertScale(disparity, real_disparity, -16,0)
#get the point cloud
depth = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(im_l),cv.IPL_DEPTH_32F,3)
cv.ReprojectIMageTo3D(real_disparity,depth, ReprojectMatrix)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is, that `FindStereoCorrespondenceBM` saves the result in the third parameter but you are using the return value, which is `None` for further computation. This leads to an error since a matrix of a certain size and type is expected.

So just change

```
cv.ConvertScale(disparity, real_disparity, -16,0)
```

to

```
cv.ConvertScale(disp, real_disparity, -16,0)
```

To run the whole script I also changed the last line to

```
ReprojectMatrix = cv.CreateMat(4,4,cv.CV_32FC1);
cv.ReprojectImageTo3D(real_disparity,depth, ReprojectMatrix)
```

This script runs without error for me. But I have not checked whether it gives the correct result.

Comment: Awsome!  Can't thank you enough.  At this point understanding the code and getting it to run without error means more than the result.  I'll be whining about that in a few days.